# unsupported media type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: ajax, react-native, redux, elixir

I'm getting this error all of a sudden:

```
21:28:14.345 [debug] ** (Plug.Parsers.UnsupportedMediaTypeError) unsupported media type application/x-www-fo
rm-urlencoded
    (plug) lib/plug/parsers.ex:231: Plug.Parsers.ensure_accepted_mimes/4
    (api) lib/api/router.ex:1: Api.Router.plug_builder_call/2
    (api) lib/plug/debugger.ex:123: Api.Router.call/2
    (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
    (cowboy) /Users/Ben/Development/Projects/vepo/api/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

When making this network request:

```
Request URL:http://192.168.20.6:4000/products/?p_id=1&s_id=1
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:415 Unsupported Media Type
Remote Address:192.168.20.6:4000
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
cache-control:max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
content-length:45284
content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8
date:Sun, 28 Jan 2018 08:40:36 GMT
server:Cowboy
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-:application/json
Content-Length:75
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host:192.168.20.6:4000
Origin:http://evil.com/
Referer:http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.js
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Query String Parameters
view source
view URL encoded
p_id:1
s_id:1
Form Data
view source
view URL encoded
s_id:1
p_id:1
image:null
price:2.53
description:kcucufufi icif Gigiuyub
```

Code to send the request:

```
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/observable/dom/ajax'

return ajax({
    body: action.payload,
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: { 'Content-': 'application/json' },
    url: `http://192.168.20.6:4000/products/?p_id=${
        action.payload.p_id
        }&s_id=${action.payload.s_id}`
}).map(response => updateEditProductInDbFulfilled(response))
    .catch(error => Observable.of(updateEditProductInDbRejected(error)))
```

I didn't actively change anything in my backend to not accept `x-www-form-urlencoded`, so why would this happen when it used to work?

Is `x-www-form-urlencoded` bad? What is the best approach to successfully send my network request? Change my code sending the request or changing the backend somehow to accept the request?

Backend is Elixir.

This is how I added Plug.Parsers (In my router):

```
  if Mix.env == :dev do
    use Plug.Debugger
  end
  plug :match
  plug Plug.Parsers, parsers: [:json],
                   pass:  ["application/json"],
                   json_decoder: Poison
  plug :dispatch
```

Comment: Is it a Phoenix application?

Comment: @JoséValim No, pure Elixir.

Comment: So can you please sure how you added Plug.Parsers in your application?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `{ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }` not `{ 'Content-': 'application/json' }`?

Comment: @JoséValim I have just added my code to add the `Plug.Parsers` to the question.

Comment: You should have `plug Plug.Parsers, parsers: [:json, :urlencoded]`, otherwise, url encoded won't be parsed.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @JoséValim - make this an answer.